# How to take input from argv[] outside of main c++

Tags: c++, argv

I'm currently attempting to take a number with argv[] from a command line. 
In other words I'm attempting to attain the 2 from

./calculator -q 2

My current setup is something along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int check_q(char* argv[]){
    float q, qa;
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == q){
       qa = atof(argv[2]);
    }
    if(atoi(argv[3]) == q){
       qa = atof(argv[4]);
    }
    if(atoi(argv[5]) == q){
       qa = atof(argv[6]);
    }
    if(atoi(argv[7]) == q){
       qa = atof(argv[8]);
    }
return qa;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    float qa = 0;
    check_q(argv);
    cout << qa << endl;

 return 0;}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In what way are your expectations not being met?

Comment: I think you've got some basic misunderstandings about characters and integers.  "-q" is a character string you should compare with strcmp or one of its kin.

Comment: And you shouldn't use == to compare int to float ever.  (Especially when one of the comparands is uninitialized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking the value of `argc` to see how many arguments were passed to the program. If you only pass two arguments, then accessing `argv[3]` will give undefined behaviour; so you must check the number of arguments first.

Also, if you're looking for an argument with the value `"-q"`, then compare with `"-q"`:

```
if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-q")
```

You are converting it to a number and comparing with an uninitialised variable, which won't do anything useful.

Comment: Whoa. this goes to show that shining your crystal ball once in a while _does_ make a difference ! Well. blimey. It turns out `-q` was from the post. I must have been very tired.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it along:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

float check_q(std::vector<std::string> const& args)
{
    int q = 42;

    for (auto it = args.begin(); it != args.end(); std::advance(it, 2))
    {
        if (std::stoi(*it) == q)
        {
            auto next = std::next(it);
            assert(next != args.end());

            return std::stof(*next);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);

    // pass it along
    check_q(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing any number of things wrong here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int check_q(char* argv[])
{
    float q, qa;           // you never assign `q` a value, so the following comparisons make no sense
    if(atoi(argv[1]) == q)   // you never check argc in main to determine if argv[whatever] is valid.  if the array isn't long enough, this will invoke undefined behavior.
    {
       qa = atof(argv[2]);  // you're assigning a value to `qa` declared in this function, leaving the one declared in main unchanged.  probably not what you intended
    }
    // and so on

    return qa;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float qa = 0;
    check_q(argv);    // this function never changes the value of `qa` that's declared in main...
    cout << qa << endl;    // ... so this will always print 0

 return 0;
```

}

You probably want to do something more along the lines of:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

float check_q(const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    if(args[1] == "-q")
    {
        return ::atof(args[2].c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        return 0.0f;   // or some other default
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);

    if(args.size() >= 3) // argv[0] is usually the name of the executable
    {
        std::cout << check_q(argv) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not enough args" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Once you're a little more experienced you'll want to use a library like [GNU getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) or [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things about this code that don't make a lot of sense or are not safe or elegant, and I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with the inspection of arguments 1,3, 5, and 7, but here's at least one issue:

`qa` in `main` will never be updated, because you don't assign the return value of `check_q` to it. The statement needs to be:

```
float qa = 0;
qa = check_q(argv);
```

Or really, just:

```
float qa = check_q(argv);
```